# Nodemailer SMTP generating ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I'm trying to implement Nodemailer in Firebase and I keep getting ENOTFOUND error as below:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smtpout.secureserver.net smtpout.secureserver.net:587
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

code: 'ECONNECTION',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
  host: 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN'

My transporter setup is:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
        port: 587,
        auth: {
            user: 'uttsgroup@uttsg-demos.com',
            pass: 'somepassword'  
        },
        secure:false,
        tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
        debug:true
    });
```

I've tried various options but all were generating the same error result.

Please, assist.

Many Thanks,

Badih

Comment: Is billing configured for your project?

Comment: @DougStevenson is billing configuration necessary?

Comment: Billing is required in order to make outgoing socket connections to services that Google doesn't control.